# How can I fill the text fields in page by selecting combo selection by dyanmicaly?

Tags: ajax

Suppose in the database there is one table (for example `student records`) with a number of columns, but my HTML page only displays a few of them. For example: a table having the columns `sno`, `sname`, `addr`, `age`, `dept`, and `dob` and my page having only 3 fields: `sno`, `sname`, `dept`. Here I display the `dept` field in a combo box control and the rest of the fields are text and empty values.

My requirement is: when I select the dept from combobox the corresponding row vlaues like `sno` and `sname` have to display automatically in the text fields. How can I do this?

Comment: Naresh, I rewrote your question to try and make it easier to understand. Please edit it further or roll it back if I altered your meaning by mistake. You may also find you'll get better responses if you post some sample code in the body of your question. HTH!

Comment: Thanku for u reply. ok i will follow that scenario for next questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You make an ajax call to your server when you change the department. Your server returns your object as JSON. Your success handler in your ajax call takes the fields it needs from your JSON object and sets the appropriate html elements to those fields. For example, if you're using jQuery:

```
var myUrl = "http://some.domain/action/";

var success = function(response) {
  $('#textField1').val(response.sno);
  $('#textField2').val(response.sname);
}

$('#myDropDown').change(function() {
  $.get(myUrl + $(this).val(), success);
});
```

If you don't want to send back all the properties of your object because you want to minimize bandwidth, you can form your own JSON object, but that's kind of a pain in the neck and if your object is not huge you might as well use whatever JSON serializer is available in the framework you're using and just serialize the object and send it through the wire.

Or here's another option. You could just make one initial AJAX call and then create a map from department to the other fields you want to set. Example:

```
var map = {};

var success = function(response) {
  for (obj in response.objects) {
    map[obj.department] = { sno: obj.sno, sname: obj.sname };
  }
}

$.get(myUrl, success);

$('#myDropDown').change(function() {
  var obj = map[$(this).val()];
  $('#textField1').val(obj.sno);
  $('#textField2').val(obj.sname);
}
```

Hope that helps.